# Community bulletin should specify if link is to MSE

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

Minor thing, but I just noticed that the community bulletin doesnt tell you if its pointing to MSO or MSE. It makes the following situation a little bit confusing -

[image]

By default you would assume that all of these links are to MSO, but actually the Profile Page Makeover links to MSE.

Comment: Does it really matter? And you can tell by looking at the URL when you mouse over the link.

Comment: Like I said, its a minor thing. But considering Im generally not too interested in MSO links, and I am in MSE links, I figured Ide bring it up. Also I looked on a few other sites and it seems like they all have this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links to MSE have an MSE icon next to them.

The links to a child-meta (such as MSO), have the vote score on them.

Comment: Looks good `+1`

Comment: They do now, but they didn't when I asked this. So now I'm happy :)